# What does "tidbit of intelligence" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

[From here](https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=oV1tXT3HigoC&pg=PT186&lpg=PT186&dq=%22tidbit%20of%20intelligence%22&source=bl&ots=bZPwPJ2qiV&sig=ACfU3U3kbbOZbpcDfUoGwDmWR9MWv-4lhQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjUqqTZn9nnAhXJlIsKHZfUC68Q6AEwAHoECAoQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22tidbit%20of%20intelligence%22&f=false):

> But on July 10, no one knew - or could have known - that this **tidbit of intelligence** would turn out to dominate history.

I've searched for definition of the word **tidbit** and the most suitable one is :

> **tidbit** - a small and particularly interesting item of gossip or
>   information.

But why do we have tidbit **of intelligence**? It doesn't make sense to me, although as far as I see it's [relatively common usage](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&sxsrf=ACYBGNTwFeRk7j4fe17pB2O5mLt1xMOFdg%3A1581965605843&ei=JeFKXqGEM6jprgS2kZHYBw&q=%22tidbit%20of%20intelligence%22&oq=%22tidbit%20of%20intelligence%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3..35i39l2.14030.15303..15600...0.0..0.154.458.2j2......0....1..gws-wiz.lDIAt89dR6Q&ved=0ahUKEwjhqu6PodnnAhWotIsKHbZIBHsQ4dUDCAo&uact=5): about 6,650 search results.

Comment: You also need to look up possible meanings of "intelligence". There is at least one which makes perfect sense here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You looked up "tidbit" but apparently not "intelligence." [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/intelligence) has

> **intelligence**
>   MASS NOUN
>
> **2.2** Military or political information.
>   *The FBI is gathering intelligence from (drum roll, please) the Internet.*

So with your definition of **tidbit**

> a small and particularly interesting item of (gossip or) information

the phrase

> this **tidbit** of **intelligence** would turn out to dominate history

means that it was a very small piece of information, but highly significant.